# EXEC query stored in a column

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to be able to get the result of a query stored in a column, parametrized by value in another one. Model is more relational ( queries are in a 1--n linked table ), but to keep it simple :

```
value | query
------------- 
25    | SELECT id, name FROM courses
12    | SELECT id, name FROM countries
```

I want to be able to get the results of the queries, so something like

```
SELECT EXEC(query + ' WHERE id = ' + value) FROM table
```

I would like to do without the application side to do that.

Is it possible ?

PS: the risk of SQL Injection does not come into play, it's already managed.

Comment: I've edited your question with the help of Google translate. hope the translation is correct....

Comment: So what would be the expected results? you want a single dataset that returns the results of each stored query? are all queries returning the same columns?

Comment: You say that it's managed but something like `SELECT EXEC(query + ' WHERE id = ' + value) FROM table` is a wide open channel for injection. The combination of injecting a raw parameter into a stored SQL query for dynamic execution does add further concerns. Is `value` an `int` at least?

Comment: When I say "its managed", its because the list of possible queries are made by ITs, and validated by Auditing, and value is an int or an int[ ]. For @ZoharPeled, all queries will return a label, for instance the name of the course or the name of the country.

Comment: Why are you storing queries in a table like this at all? It has a major code smell that the design went the wrong direction. Stored procedures, views, anything is better than storing queries. There are just so many things that can go wrong with this approach. And the sql injection issue...

Comment: As I said, I tried to make my case as simple as possible. In reality, queries are not directly stored, splitted into different columns like table, key, label, etc. The purpose is to automatise machine decisions when a combinaison of tests is achieved; the tests and the combinaisons are built by the user itself, but has an infinite ( or quite ) number of possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One posible approach is to generate and execute a dynamic statement for all your possible `SELECT` statements.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Statements (
    [value] int,
    [query] nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Statements 
   ([value], [query])
VALUES
    (25, N'SELECT id, name FROM courses'),
    (12, N'SELECT id, name FROM countries')
```

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''
SELECT @stm = (
   SELECT 
      CONCAT(
         [query],
         N' WHERE id = ',
         [value],
         N'; '
      )
   FROM #Statements
   FOR XML PATH('')
   )
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Generated statements:

```
SELECT id, name FROM courses WHERE id = 25; 
SELECT id, name FROM countries WHERE id = 12;
```

If you want to retrieve the results from all your statements into a single result set and if columns `id` and `name` have compatible data types, you can execute next statement (with possible `CONVERT` calls):

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''
SELECT @stm = STUFF(
   (    
   SELECT 
      CONCAT(
         N'UNION ALL ',
         [query],
         N' WHERE id = ',
         [value],
         N' '
      )
   FROM #Statements
   FOR XML PATH('')
   ),
   1, 10, N'')
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Comment: Personally, *just* in case, I would use `QUOTENAME([value],'''')` here. I realise that changes the value to a `varchar`, and it was an `int` (within the dynamic SQL), but SQL Server will implicitly convert that value back to a `int` when it runs the query. The key thing about using `QUOTENAME` though is that *if* `[value]` is a `(n)varchar` (which to OPs question implies) then just concatenating the raw value is an injection risk as well. We don't have any evidence of how the OP is "sanitising" their parameters and statements, so I would say it far better to err on the side of caution here.

Comment: @Larnu, you are absolutly right. I hope that OP will use `value` column data carefully and consider `QUOTENAME` as an option. Thanks for this comment.

Comment: I dono why my comment disappeared. I said thanks, FOR XML was a good tip; I finally achieved what I want by concatening the first query for a union all, and join on it on the second one. Thanks again !