# Delete all Users in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete all Users after have finished import Bacpac file. So I try Script as below when it said executed successfully but I refresh the database and saw that user still exists. Does anyone have a script or method for solving this case? Thank you for sharing!

```
USE Catalog
GO
SELECT 'DROP USER ['+name+'];' 
FROM sys.sysusers 
WHERE name not in ('guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys','public')
    and name not like 'db%'
```

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Looks like you just selected, maybe you need to store the results in a temporary table and then exec the queries.
take a look here, please. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56476215/10819830

Comment: side note: I would never drop users using wildcrds! I mean, what could possibly go wrong!

Comment: A SELECT does not execute a DROP ! @Meyssam_Toluie gives you a correct form of your uncomplete script. But some user won't be discarded with this script if they have a link to other objet, like to be the owner of a SQL schema...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query only generates your desired code. It did not execute it.

```
USE Catalog
GO
DELCARE @Command nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @Command += 'DROP USER ['+name+'];' 
FROM sys.sysusers 
WHERE name not in ('guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys','public')
    and name not like 'db%'

EXEC (@Command);
```

Comment: @HoangLe Please accept the answer if it solves your question.